# MVC - ClientValidationEnabled = true, yet there is still a postback, ruining my jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, postback

I have some jQuery on my page that shows a div with some controls when a button is clicked.
Originally the div is hidden.

I have ClientValidationEnabled = true set in my web.config.
If I click the show button, the div with the controls shows, but if I fill in some data, and click the submit button, instead of the client-side validation kicking in, the page is reloaded and I am back to the start again, with my div hidden.

What could be causing this?

Here is my view...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<h2>cardiac</h2>

<br>
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>cardiac</legend>
        <div id ="confirmdiv" class="notificationdiv" align="center">  
            Please check sample type, this screen is only for <b>Cardiac</b> results and <b>NOT</b> Liquid Cardiac.
            <br />    
            <input type ="button" id ="buttonConfirm" value ="Confirm"/>
            <input type ="button" id ="buttonBack" value ="Back"/>
        </div>
        <div id ="formdiv" style="display:none;">
            <br>
            Please fill in your results...    
            <br/>
            @Html.Partial("_CreateOrEdit", Model)    

            <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </div>
    </fieldset>
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#buttonConfirm").click(function () {
            $("#confirmdiv").hide();
            $("#formdiv").show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are including jQuery, but not the other required scripts.

Try adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

These will implement the validation attributes needed.

Edit: oops and I am assuming you have the necessary attributes on your model to invoke the validation as required